# Filter array of objects on property with NSPredicate

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering, nspredicate

I have an array of Studios. Each studio, has a property called studioName.

I need my searchfield to filter the studios, based on the studioName, applied to the searchfield by the user.

Here's my current code:

```
var studios = [Studio]()
var filteredStudios = [Studio]()
var studiosToDisplay = [Studio]()

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text

    print("SEARCH TEXT: \(searchText)")

    if searchText == nil || searchText!.isEmpty {
        studiosToDisplay = studios
        self.resultTableView.reloadData()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showResultsBeforeSearchingNotification", object: nil) //Calls SearchVC
    } else {
        studiosToDisplay.removeAll()
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "studioName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText!)
        let array = (self.studios as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        studiosToDisplay = array as! [Studio]
        self.resultTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

It's just not working wight, right now.. It filters, but I end up with the same Studio left each time, no matter what I put in the searchfield.

I guess I need to make the predicate know, that it has to look at the single object in the array, each time. But I just can't figure out how.
I tried to add "ANY" in the format, but that crashes my app.

Comment: You should tag your question properly as it seems that you are using Swift 2 (I recommend updating your Xcode to the latest Xcode available at the APP Store)

Comment: On a side note: checking for nil with `searchText  == nil`, then force unwrapping (`searchText!`) is really bad practice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is unnecessarily complex. There's no need for `NSPredicate` here.

```
var studios = [Studio]()
var filteredStudios = [Studio]()
var studiosToDisplay = [Studio]()

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text

    print("SEARCH TEXT: \(searchText)")

    if let searchText = searchText, !searchText.isEmpty {
        studiosToDisplay = studios.filter{ $0.studioName.contains(searchText) }
    }
    else {
        studiosToDisplay = studios
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showResultsBeforeSearchingNotification", object: nil) //Calls SearchVC
    }

    self.resultTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Alexander .. Here's the code I ended up using:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text

    if let searchText = searchText {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            self.studiosToDisplay = self.studios.filter { $0.studioName!.containsString(searchText) }
            for studio in self.studiosToDisplay {
                print("\(studio.studioName!)")
            }
        }
        else {
            self.studiosToDisplay = self.studios
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showResultsBeforeSearchingNotification", object: nil) // Calls SearchVC
        }
    }

    self.resultTableView.reloadData()

}
```

I figured out, that my former code, with the NSPredicate actually was functional - I was just presenting the wrong array in my tableview.. Oops.. But now it works, and I stick to the more simple code. Don't know why I didn't think of using the $0-function :) .. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You can use a guard statement to bind `searchText` without that extra level of indentation